# Is there any solution to disable Javascript style changes in print?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, printing

Is there any solution to disable Javascript style changes in print?

For instance, if I'm hiding something through Javascript but I want to include that hidden info in print.

I hid a `div` using Javascript and I want to show that `div` if Javascript is disabled. Now the problem is, because `div` is hidden using Javascript it's also not showing when the page is printed.

Comment: @Andy E's head - Thanks to edit my question for better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a print stylesheet, along with `!important` statements to force the element to be visible for printing.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv { display: block!important; }
```

Comment: It is important to note that when removing CSS translations applied by JS, rotations should be set to 0, and translations need to be set to the opposite (so if you translate up 50px with JS, translate down 50px for printing).

Answer (score 3):

I've found a workaround (at least, it works for me). In my instance i had a basic html page with some styling (screen.css & print.css) plus some javascript to progressively enhance the page with extra features, etc.

When it came time to print the page i realised that the js was affecting the layout (since i was doing some css styling via jquery).

What i ended up doing was this:

**in "screen.css"**

```
body {
    background-color: #ccc; /* or whatever colour your designer chose; if it NEEDS to be white, simply change something else (e.g. background-image, font-size, etc.) */
}
```

**in "print.css"**

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**in "the-javascript-file.js"**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if (isPrinting() == false)
    {
        init();
    }
});

function isPrinting()
{
    var isPrint = false;
    /* I'm not 100% sure about the string literal check 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
       should do some testing here with other values || other attributes...
       (font-size, color, line-height, other attributes that will have the 
       greatest difference / variation between "screen" and "print" styles)
    */
    if ($('body').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
    {
        isPrint = true;
    }
    return isPrint;
}

function init()
{
    // All sorts of awesome goes here
}
```

And that was it! It worked!

Here's an overview of what's happening:

- User loads page
- Browser loads "screen.css"
- Body background colour is set to "#ccc"
- Browser loads "the-javascript-file.js"
- JS checks background colour... it's "#ccc"...
- JS does its thing
- User hits print command
- Browser loads "print.css"
- Body background colour changes to "#fff"
- Browser loads "the-javascript-file.js"
- JS checks body background colour
- JS realises background colour is "#fff"
- JS does nothing :)

Hope this helps someone out there :)

Comment: That's an... interesting idea. However it contradicts the principle of separation of concerns. Once you decide to change your CSS files, the JS will break.

Comment: Good point Pumbaa80 :) I completely agree and I don't like the dependency either, but, i'd rather have one dependency that's well documented than a 100 or so !important rules all over the place :-/

Comment: Using `important` in print stylesheets is totally common and there's nothing wrong with that. Another problem with your solution is that it doesn't work if screen and print design are identical (prior to applying JS)

Comment: well enhancing upon @barryels idea, we can use a div tag with an id specifically for this purpose in the (footer maybe and hide it even forever!). Make sure this div tag is never used for contents at all. This way we have our exclusive variable in html for javascript to read.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `!important` has already been mentioned, but it is a blunt instrument and things get very complicated once you start needing to override things which are already `!important`.

One of the great benefits of CSS is that it allows you to separate style from structure. Instead of using JS to manipulate the *style* of an element, use it to manipulate the *structure*. For example, by manipulating the `className` property.

Your screen media stylesheet can then hide the element, while leaving it visible for the print media stylesheet.

This has the additional benefit that you don't need to think about having to override these styles as they won't apply in the first place (for print).

Comment: you mean i should add separate class to `div` to show in print. can you explain in detail

Comment: @met: create a class like `visible-in-print` which is styled to `display: none` for `screen` and add that class to elements you want to hide instead of using inline styles.

Comment: but i can't keep `display:none` in css. I'm hiding as this `document.write('<style type="text/css" media="screen">#sitemapContainer { display: none; }</style>');`